# Xcode 13, Monterey, Help Book doesn't work anymore

Tags: macos, xcode13, macos-monterey

in my application on macOS, objective-c, i have a help book bundle. It worked in former macOS but not anymore in macOS Monterey. I just get a blank help book window on opening "help" in the menu.

Any advice?

Edit: After revealing this post in the apple dev forum -> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693559?answerId=699012022#699012022
i discovered it works once the application is in the application folder - so for testing the help book just move the app from the derived data folder to the application folder. It seems to be a sandbox issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a sandbox issue. Moving the application from derived data to the application folder makes the help book appear as normal.

Also tested with archived application on M1 MacBook Pro, Monterey.
The bug is reported to Apple so let's see if they loosen the reins for developers / debug mode to avoid this workaround.